# C# WPF if ComboBox Equal multiple conditions

Tags: c#, wpf

This seems like a real simple one, but after some searching i cannot find a simple answer.
I have a combobox that i want to execute the same command if it meets any one of several conditions..
like

```
 if (comboBox.Text == "Value") or (comboBox.Text == "Value2") or (comboBox.Text == "Value3")
  {
   do the same thing for all 3 values
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the || (and or) operator?

Comment: instead of "or" || You should use operator. In addition, it would be more appropriate to operate according to the index selected as comboBox.SelectedIndex == 0.

Comment: @saklanmaz, selected index, be careful.  What if the list changes and a new value is inserted somewhere in between, thus distorting the original ordinal position and break unexpectedly.

Answer (score -2):

```cs
if ((boxItem8 == "value1") || (boxItem8 == "value2"))
```